# Как изменить используемую базу Firebase Realtime

Tags: android, firebase, realtime

Всем привет) такое горе случилось) хотел удалить добавленное приложение к базе, а удалил еще и базу =( создал новую залил данные а подвязать к приложению не могу =( выручайте более опытные коллеги, пробовал так:
tools ->Firebase->
пишет уже connected
как отвязать и прицепить новую.
Уже мысли насчет того чтобы полностью переписать приложение, но желание это делать минимальное. Хочется обойтись малой кровью

Comment: не пользуйтесь UI методами для подключения сторонних зависимостей - они сложные и малофункциональные. Всё что нужно для подключения того или иного проекта к приложения - файл `google-services.json` скачайте нужный из консоли и замените им текущий.

Comment: Спасибо, уже переписал на новом приложении с подключением прежним способом. Но за способ спасибо, как же я забыл про это. Ведь я знал)) теперь точно не забуду